# Using memory allocated by sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory() in native code

Tags: java, java-native-interface, unsafe

I am trying to allocate memory using sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory() and access it in native code.

however, it seems the long value returned by allocateMemory doesn't quite work as the right address in C code.

```
            Unsafe unsafe = getUnsafe();
            long address = unsafe.allocateMemory(64);

            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i += 8)
                unsafe.putByte(memory + i, (byte) 0xFF);

            nativeMethod(address);
```

However in my native code when I try to access 'address' as a pointer, it doesn't work :(

**Update:** I have attached an image showing the issue. 
I passed the 'address' to the native code, however, examining the memory at that location doesnt show the 0xFF values I put in there.

**Image:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoIYG.png

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work *how*? You'll need to show the native code, too.

Comment: Ok I have explained the 'how' and even attached an image now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's working perfectly fine! Your "for" loop sets every eighth byte to `0xff`, and if you look closely at the display and count, you'll see that every eighth byte *is* `0xff`. There are some other random values in there because `Unsafe. allocateMemory()` doesn't return zeroed memory; it returns uninitialized memory, just like C's `malloc()`.

If you changed that "i += 8" to just "i++", then *every* byte would be `0xff`; it'd be worth doing that experiment to prove to yourself that it's working.

Comment: you are correct. thanks! i overlooked the fact that the memory allocation is takes a 'byte' param and had everything messed up basically. remind me to buy you a beer if we meet :)