# Is there a delete like function in Java similar to c++ such that setting an item to null hints the GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, copy, variable-assignment

When creating my own singly linked list class I noticed that the push and pop functions seems to work as expected. Although in the `pop_back()` method I set `headTmp = null` to indicate that this is no longer required. Also, can this potentially screw up the assignment to tmp since it is assigned to headTmp.data? Is this assignment a copy or a reference assignment to headTmp.data? I am unsure if Java does copies outside of arguments to functions.

In C++ the assignment would be a copy and then I would have a pointer and just delete the headTmp item. Do I need to have `headTmp = null` in this code or does this not help anything or potentially hurt the assignment of the data and is just setting the `prev.next = null` enough and will the GC will handle this clean up? Should I think about garbage collection similar to a shared pointer in C++ where reference counting is used such that when nothing is pointing to this object it gets cleaned up?  I am used to cleaning up my own garbage

```
package dynamiclist;

public class LinkedList<T>
{
    public T pop_back()
    {
        Node<T> prev = null;
        Node<T> headTmp = head;

        while ( headTmp.next != null)
        {
            prev = headTmp;
            headTmp  = headTmp.next;
        }

        T tmp = headTmp.data;
        headTmp = null;  // does this help in GC at all? Does it effect previous assignment of tmp?

        prev.next = null;
        return tmp;
    }

    public void push_back(T t)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node<T>(t);
            return;
        }

        Node<T> headTmp = head;
        while (headTmp.next != null)
        {
            headTmp= headTmp.next;
        }

        headTmp.next = new Node<T>(t);
        headTmp.next.next=null;
    }

    public void printList()
    {
        Node<T> headTmp = head;
        while ( headTmp!=null)
        {
            headTmp.printNode();
            headTmp = headTmp.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private Node<T> head;
}
```

Comment: I think you will find http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html to be a very informative read.

Comment: headTmp is about to go out of scope at the point you are nulling it, so nulling it is just a waste of time and space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the GC determines that no more references exist to an object (weak references do not affect this, see [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)), that object is marked for deletion, and deletion can happen at any time.

Setting a field to null will mark that object as discardable presuming no other references exist, which means it's a candidate for deletion at a later time. You don't *have* to set the field to null although it's frequently appropriate with respect to your application's logic (GC aside). Even if you don't set fields to null, when the last reference to the enclosing object disappears, so do the references to the objects its fields refer to (unless of course they are referred to in other places).

You may wish to check out the following two articles:

- [How the garbage collector works](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)
- [Reference types](http://neverfear.org/blog/view/150/Strong_Soft_Weak_and_Phantom_References_Java)

Comment: Sounds good. What about the assignment though for T tmp = headTmp.data? Is this a reference or a copy? When I set the headTmp to null afterwards what happens?

Comment: Basically, every object variable in Java is a pointer. So tmp now refers to the same object as headTmp.data. As for setting headTmp to null, the only thing that happens is headTmp is set to null. The general rule holds: If the object previously referred to by headTmp no longer has any references, it will be up for GC. Setting headTmp to null is unnecessary here (headTmp is local and the ref goes away on return anyways). The real magic is in the next line, prev.next = null, because up to that point, the item is still referenced in the list (prev.next referred to the same object as headTmp).

Comment: Continued: prev.next is likely the last remaining reference to the item, so at that point, the item that was referred to by prev.next is up for collection.

Comment: I think I got it now so just because the headTmp object had a member named data doesn't matter because when I do the assignment of tmp = headTmp.data this is saying that tmp points to that object independently and that the assignment of headTmp = null doesn't effect this.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to set it to `null`. As soon as the reference is broken (no more instances refer to the object) it will automatically be cleaned by the garbage collector.

Althrough it is not a bad thing to set something to `null` (basically omitting the former link), it is not a guarantee that the object will be cleaned. If some other instance is still referring to the pointer, than the garbage collector will not clean it until all instances that refer to the original object have omitted their relation.

Long story short, it's not necessary, but it won't hurt.

As a short reference to http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html:

1. You as Java programmer can not force Garbage collection in Java; it will only trigger if JVM thinks it needs a garbage collection based on Java heap size.

If you assign `null` to an object, you are omitting its link. This is done automatically at the end of a scope. Since the garbage-collector is only run when Java needs memory, it is hardly useful.

And on a quick side-note (if you are used to C++):

Java handles all objects and arrays as pointers. If you want to duplicate them, you will have to deep-copy them.

Comment: bas can you check out my comment above to Jason C about the assignment? This is where I am getting a little confused.

Comment: which part is confusing?

Comment: Philosophical comment on "it won't hurt": It certainly doesn't negatively affect the code, but it *is* detrimental in a bigger picture sense if the programmer does not understand why it's unnecessary.

Comment: It actually _can_ hurt performance -- not of the object being GC'ed, but of the object that used to "own" it. Some JVMs keep track of which objects have been modified, and modifying the owner class can put more strain on the GC (if it hasn't been modified, the GC can fast-path its GC). If you're creating something like a collection class, whose lifecycle is expected to outlive its elements, you should definitely null them out on removal. Otherwise, you probably shouldn't. And of course, none of this applies to local variables, which was the OP's question (but +1 to @JasonC's point).

Comment: yshavit so are you saying that in this case since this is a deletion on the collection that I should null it out? Also, headTmp in this case is a local variable but it is referring to the collection item at the end of the list. So does setting this to null effect the collection item or just change the local variable to point to null

Comment: Keep in mind, compilers are extremely smart, and will generally do a very good job of removing unnecessary assignments, unused variables, etc.

Comment: @bjackfly Since it's a local variable, setting it to `null` has exactly zero effect. All it does is lower the reference count by 1, which would happen anyway when the local variable goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sun.misc.Unsafe` class -- in particular, `allocateMemory` and `freeMemory` methods are akin to `malloc` and `free` in C:

- http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/direct-memory-access-in-java/
- [Using memory allocated by sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory() in native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323416/using-memory-allocated-by-sun-misc-unsafe-allocatememory-in-native-code)
- http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2012/10/compact-off-heap-structurestuples-in.html
- http://java-performance.info/memory-allocation-in-java/
- http://mishadoff.github.io/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/

Although don't expect this to be necessarily faster -- in fact, it may even slow things down:

- http://mentablog.soliveirajr.com/2012/11/which-one-is-faster-java-heap-or-native-memory/

You may also be interested in the alternative(s) discussed in the following thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/l4zPzatmhtU